# print page margins doesnt work in chrome and ie

Tags: html, css, css-paged-media

I want to set margin-top and bottom to my print page for writing header and footer.

I did it in Firefox. But it doesn't work in chrome and internet explorer.

When I used `@page` code it works in chrome. But I cant write header on the top and footer on the bottom. How can I solve this problem?

Here is my code

pagination.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTL> 
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-9">
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
<meta name="googlebot" content="noindex">
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">    
<title>Brove.NET ISO Yazılımı</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/pagination.css" />
</head>

<body>
<table class="header" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>header
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="content" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">
   content
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="footer" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>footer
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

pagination.css

```
@media screen{
.header{
    width:768px;
    height:100px;
    border:2px solid #000;
}

.content{
    width:768px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    height:1000px;
}

.footer{
    width:768px;
    height:100px;
    border:2px solid #000;
}
}

@media print{

.header{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:768px;
    height:100px;
    border:2px solid #000;
}

.content{
    width:768px;
    margin-top:120px;
    margin-bottom:120px;
    height:1000px;
}

.footer{
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:768px;
    height:100px;
    border:2px solid #000;
}

@page{
    margin-bottom:150px;
}


}
```

IE screenshot:

[image]

Firefox screenshot:

[image]

Chrome screenshot:

[image]

Comment: it sets margin to the page. I want to set it at content table